# Append text to div from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, textarea

I am trying to make a simple editor where the user can enter text and upon hitting the edit button it will append that text to the end of the `id="textArea"`. Nothing happens when I hit the edit button after entering text in the textarea.

If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong or a better way to do this I'd appreciate it, I have seen other ways of doing it but I'm just not sure why this way isn't working. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function edit(){

      var editorText = document.getElementById("editor").value;
      $("#textArea")append("editorText");
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
<form>
  Text Editor
<br/>
  <textarea id="editor">
  </textarea>
<br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="edit()">
</form>
  </div>
<br>

  <div id="textArea">

<h2><a name="year1"></a>Document</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse laoreet nisl velit, at elementum enim blandit in. Suspendisse sit amet posuere ex. Donec sit amet commodo nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam vitae tincidunt metus. Suspendisse ex ligula, placerat convallis varius in, placerat et ipsum. Pellentesque et neque nec nisl consectetur fringilla ut tristique ligula. Aliquam in sem turpis.
</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: After following some of the suggestions, I still had no luck. Here is the new code I am trying to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  function edit(){
 $("#editor").append("editorText");
}
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
<form>
  Text Editor
<br/>
  <textarea id="editor">
  </textarea>
<br/>
  <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit()">
</form>
  </div>

<br>

  <div id="textArea">

<h2><a name="year1"></a>Document</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse laoreet nisl velit, at elementum enim blandit in. Suspendisse sit amet posuere ex. Donec sit amet commodo nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam vitae tincidunt metus. Suspendisse ex ligula, placerat convallis varius in, placerat et ipsum. Pellentesque et neque nec nisl consectetur fringilla ut tristique ligula. Aliquam in sem turpis.
</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use two separate `<script>` tags as you cannot place JS code within a script tag with a `src` attribute. Also note that your HTML is invalid as you have a couple of missing start/end tags.

Comment: I think you just missed a dot in the append method. Also I don't think you need the type="submit" in the input.

Comment: $("#textArea")append("editorText");  will be $("#textArea").append("editorText"); however if you using jQuery. i didn't see you include jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append the string "editorText" instead of the variable and you missed one .

You should do:

```
$("#textArea").append(editorText);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your button and edit function as below

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit()">

function edit(){
   $("#editor").append("editorText");
}
```

Comment: I made the changes exactly as you prescribed and nothing happens when I press the edit button. I am sure your code is right, I tried all the suggestions listed in the answers and although I see the button and text box, none of them edited the text inside the div.

Comment: if you want to change text in textarea, you should use .text() not .append(). try $("#editor").text("editorText");

Answer (score 0):

You can't append the text content of the textarea to a element. Instead of doing that, try this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
  $('#textArea').text($('#editor').val());
});
```

That is jQuery. When you click the submit button, what will happen is the text content of the `id="textArea"` would be the text content of the `#editor`. You can change the `text()` to `html()` if you ever want to render the elements that are typed in the `#editor` like `<p>This is a paragraph</p>`.